# Wrong library version used (libpng)

Tags: apt, libpng

I installed a long time ago the `libpng12-dev` package with the apt-get command. It  installed libpng-1.2.54.

But now I have a project that require the libpng-1.6.16 version. Since it's not available on a ppa I did the following :

- I uninstalled the libpng12-dev library, with `apt-get remove`
- I installed the new library manually

But when I executed my program it's still tells me taht it's using the 1.2.54 version. So I checked some few sthing and it seems that the library is still installed :

```
$identify -list format | grep PNG
```

prints

```
MNG* PNG       rw+   Multiple-image Network Graphics (libpng 1.2.54)
      PNG* PNG       rw-   Portable Network Graphics (libpng 1.2.54)
```

or

```
$ apt-cache policy libpng12-dev
```

prints

```
libpng12-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.54-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.2.54-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

and

```
$ apt-cache policy libpng12-0
```

prints

```
libpng12-0:
  Installed: 1.2.54-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.2.54-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.54-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Is it possible to redirect the program to use the good library at run time? Or to change the configuration to use the last installed version instead?

Answer (score 1):

Undo your manual installation, and install the libpng 1.6 version which comes with Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libpng16-16
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. I managed to solve it by compiling the project with my local library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544445/libpng-warning-incompatible-libpng-version-in-application-and-library. But yet it's not really what I was looking for. I still can't see why it keeps linking me to the oldest version. I also tried editing my LD_LIBRARY_PATH but that didn't change anything.